# Implement Vector of Map in c++

Tags: c++

I want to use vector of Map in c++.
I have list of mapped values, which I want to store as map in vector.
My requirement goes something like this:
1. For N columns, I have a map of values . 
2. I want to maintain map of  for each i in N.

I am trying to maintain this in Vector >. 
Please let me know how to make it work.

I am using following code to add mappings

```
void fun() 
{
vector< map < string, int> > myVect;
myVect.push_back(new map< string, int> );
myVect.push_back(new map< string, int> );

map< string, int> entry1 = myVect[0];

entry1["ABC"] = 1;
entry1["DEF"] = 2;

map< string, int> entry2 = myVect[1];

entry1["ABC"] = 5;
entry1["RKD"] = 9;
}
```

Why doesn't work ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You seem to have very specific idea of what you want to achieve, so where exactly is your problem?

Comment: eg: vector<map<string, int> x; <br/> to make entry I use x.push_back(new map<string, int>); <br/> Now, to access entry in vector, I use map<string, int> entry = x[i] and add map value to it as entry.add()

Comment: Ok, so you seem to have it working. What is your problem?

Comment: @Rahul I've updated my answer with detail from your comment. Your declaration of the structure was fine, but your insertion had an error.

Comment: Did you look at your question *at all* while you wrote it? Did you notice that some pretty important parts of it are missing? Did you notice that when asking a question, the sidebar describes how to format code? Please, when you ask questions, try to make them readable. If you can't be bothered to read what you wrote, do you expect anyone else to? Code can be marked up either by surrounding it with backticks (`\``), or by indenting it by 4 spaces. Or simply select the code and click the `{ }` button.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It doesn't work as expected, it doesn't compile, what is wrong with code. This code probably doesn't compile at all, because you push_back pointer to map not map itself.

Comment: When asking about code that does not work, always *quote the error* you are seeing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your example, you are pushing back using a pointer (via `new`), and not by const reference or value. Your 'vector of maps' declaration is fine, but the insertion is causing a compiler error.

To push a map into the vector, use the form:

```
std::map<std::string,int> m;
// populate m if needed
x.push_back(m);
```

or simply

```
x.push_back(std::map<std::string,int>());
```

if you want to push an empty map.

Note that `new` is not needed here.

Answer (score 5):

Justin answered the big part of it but another issue is:

```
map< string, int> entry1 = myVect[0];
```

This will copy the map from your vector. You probably want a reference instead:

```
map< string, int>& entry1 = myVect[0];
```